# Cant build program on Objective-C using GNUstep

Tags: objective-c, linux, gnustep, gnu-make

I'm trying to build hello world on Objective-C on Linux (Ubuntu).
main.c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(void)
{

    NSLog(@"asdasd");  
    return 0;
}
```

I don't think there is the error here. Then i'd created Makefile:

```
GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES = /usr/share/GNUstep/Makefiles

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make
TOOL_NAME = main
main_OBJC_FILES = main.m
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make
```

And then i run "make":

```
This is gnustep-make 2.2.0. Type 'make print-gnustep-make-help' for help.
Making all for tool main...
make[1]: GNUmakefile: no such file or directory
```

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Maybe you need to rename your Makefile to GNUmakefile, as the error says...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing the GNUstep libraries and tools on an Ubuntu system is simple, just sudo apt-get install gnustep gnustep-devel and you're all set (seriously, Apt is, as far as I know, the easiest way to install software - as long as it's in the repositories).
Turns out I had named it `GNUMakefile`, while I should have named it `GNUmakefile`.

**source.m**:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main(void)
{
    NSLog(@"asdasd");  
    return 0;
}
```

**GNUmakefile:**

```
GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES = /usr/share/GNUstep/Makefiles

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make
TOOL_NAME = app
app_OBJC_FILES = source.m
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make
```

**And I can run it.**

```
us@com:~/ObjectiveC$ make
This is gnustep-make 2.6.0. Type 'make print-gnustep-make-help' for help.
Making all for tool app...
 Compiling file source.m ...
 Linking tool app ...

us@com:~/ObjectiveC$ ./obj/app
2011-11-22 18:01:21.285 app[8042] asdasd
```